# How to bind an object value to HTML in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want to print values from a single object in HTML, but it is throwing an error.

```js
{
  "id": "221",
  "user_id": "455",
  "membership_id": "3",
  "is_cemetery": "0",
  "first_name": "tinku",
  "last_name": "tinku",
  "gender": "male",
  "dob": "2019-03-16",
  "i_am": "",
  "looking_for": "",
  "phone": "9876543210",
  "street": "",
  "city": "mohali",
  "state": "",
  "country": "GE",
  "zipcode": "160055",
  "photo": "",
  "description": "test",
  "created_date": "2019-05-27 10:23:46",
  "country_name": "Georgia",
  "image": false,
  "dogs": [{
    "id": "336",
    "user_id": "455",
    "agency_name": "tinkurana99",
    "dog_name": "Tom",
    "training_status": "",
    "selectbreed": "Cross",
    "breed": "261",
    "dog_color": "red",
    "dog_gender": "male",
    "maturity": "Puppy",
    "age_type": "",
    "dog_age": "",
    "age_year": "2",
    "age_month": "2",
    "age_week": "2",
    "eating_habit": "",
    "istrained": "Yes",
    "vaccinated": "yes",
    "description": "Doggy Dating agency",
    "dog_photo": "uploads/5cec705462b13.jpeg",
    "cemetery": "No",
    "start_year": "",
    "end_year": "",
    "cemetery_content": "",
    "iam_status": "4",
    "dog_price": "",
    "status": "active",
    "admin_status": "Approve",
    "created_date": "2019-05-27 10:03:32",
    "breed_name": "Australian Terrier-Akita Inu"
  }]
}
```

So this object is passed from a TS file:

```js
this.userData = this.response.data;
```

In the HTML I am accessing the values like this:

```
{{ userData.city }}
```

But it is throwing an error that city is `undefined`. I am using Ionic framework v3 and Angular v5.

Comment: Please provide the code including the part where you fetch the data and the html part where userData.city is contained in

Comment: Error is not that city is undefined. Error is `cannot read property city OF undefined` which means `userData` is undefined. It happens because you're getting data only after template is instantiated. Use safe navigation operator `{{userData?.city}}` to work around that.

Comment: The question is very vague. Show show proper code snippet where we can see at where you are assigning data to the variable. But consider how things work, the comment provided by @ritaj might be the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this:

```
{{userData?.city}}
```

Instead of:

```
{{userData.city}}
```

`?` is the safe navigation operator. It checks whether the variable is null or undefined, so that our template won't try to select a property of something falsy.